# Bootstrap for iOs -- Is there something similar available?

Tags: iphone

I normally use twitter bootstrap to power our websites with great and interactive HTML5 stuff.

I recently started playing with iOs and started app development and wanted to know if there is something like twitter bootstrap or something else available for iOs to use all these great buttons and everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you go through these links:

- [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/)
- [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)
- [BButton](https://github.com/jessesquires/BButton)

I think that BButton is the one that's more like what you are looking for. I also think that this is a good start. Just don't end up making those buttons in Photoshop and using them as button images because they will usually require a lot of memory (in terms of how much memory a button should require - drawing an image is a costly operation and will take up much more resources than doing those buttons programmatically).

Good luck!

P.S. It would take you about 2 minutes to do a google search on `twitter bootstrap ios (library | buttons | text | fonts | etc.)' and to get these links.